# References for modular forms

Tags: reference-request, modular-forms

I am looking for introductive and more advanced books about modular forms and elliptic curves which explore the links with algebraic number theory / number theory and that would be pleasant to read ideally since I will be working on this topic by myself :)
I have solid basis in algebraic number theory and I was thinking about working on this topic and some basic algebraic geometry before starting class field theory

Comment: Diamond and Shurman "A First Course in Modular Forms" sounds about right. It has more than plenty of elliptic curve connections, and even goes into algebraic curves/Jacobian varieties, Riemann zeta, etc.